# App don't reinstall every time after "build" on apple watch (Second target)

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

The application on watch executes the old code. If write a new line code and run, then the old code will be executed. If remove the application from watch and run, the new code works. The application on watch does not reset itself after launch.
This is a problem with the second target, with the first target all works well.

Comment: Please display your code

Comment: It's a large project